# Is it possible to write a bunch of pixels in gl_FragColor?

Tags: opengl, opengl-es

Has anyone familiar with some sort of **OpenGL magic** to get rid of **calculating bunch of pixels in fragment shader** instead of only 1? Especially this issue is hot for OpenGL ES in fact meanwile flaws mobile platforms and necessary of doing things in more accurate (in performance meaning) way on it.

Are any conclusions or ideas out there?

P.S. it's known shader due to GPU architecture organisation is run in parallel for each texture monad. But maybe there techniques to raise it from one pixel to a group of ones or to implement your own glTexture organisation. A lot of work could be done faster this way within GPU.

Comment: `-1` *A lot of work could be done faster this way within GPU.* Any proof of that? It sounds more like a wishful thinking / rant than actual technical question. Voted to close. And the GPU is built that way exactly because it's faster. It might well be that it internally uses one unit to calculate a bunch of fragments; it's beyond the scope of OpenGL anyway.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz I agree, but wouldn't vote to close - lets tell him why not.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz Please check [here](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs448f/lectures/3.1/Fast%20Filtering%20Continued.pdf) is my point to say _A lot of work could be done faster this way within GPU_. We have to keep in mind that GPU is built that way because it's faster for most (but not all of them) cases. Image processing has wide range of tasks (for example for smoothing) which output is depended on local area of neighboring pixels. That is why pure parallel implementation performs it quite bad. But you're right _it's beyond the scope of OpenGL anyway_.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OpenGL does not support writing to multiple fragments (meaning with distinct coordinates) in a shader, for good reason, it would obstruct the GPUs ability to compute each fragment in parallel, which is its greatest strength.

The structure of shaders may appear weird at first because an entire program is written for only one vertex or fragment. You might wonder why can't you "see" what is going on in neighboring parts?
The reason is an instance of the shader program runs for each output fragment, on each core/thread simultaneously, so they must all be independent of one another.
Parallel, independent, processing allows GPUs to render quickly, because the total time to process a batch of pixels is only as long as the single most intensive pixel.

Adding outputs with differing coordinates greatly complicates this.
Suppose a single fragment was written to by two or more instances of a shader.
To ensure correct results, the GPU can either assign one to be an authority and ignore the other (how does it know which will write?)
Or you can add a mutex, and have one wait around for the other to finish.
The other option is to allow a race condition regarding whichever one finishes first.

Either way this would immensely slows down the process, make the shaders ugly, and introduces incorrect and unpredictable behaviour.

Comment: Thank you, guys, for the inside. It seems dull to bring hybrid (parallel in accompany with consequent) functionality to GPU and that's why for now it's impossible. All's clear.

Answer (score 5):

Well firstly you **can** calculate multiple outputs from a single fragment shader in OpenGL 3 and up. A framebuffer object can have more than one RGBA surfaces (Renderbuffer Objects) attached and generate an RGBA for each of them by using gl_FragData[n] instead of gl_FragColor. See chapter 8 of the 5th edition OpenGL SuperBible.

However, the multiple outputs can only be generated for the same X,Y pixel coordinates in each buffer. This is for the same reason that an older style fragment shader can only generate one output, and can't change gl_FragCoord. OpenGL guarantees that in rendering any primitive, one and only one fragment shader will write to any X,Y pixel in the destination framebuffer(s).

If a fragment shader could generate multiple pixel values at different X,Y coords, it might try to write to the same destination pixel as another execution of the same fragment shader. Same if the fragment shader could change the pixel X or Y. This is the classic multiple threads trying to update shared memory problem.

One way to solve it would be to say "if this happens, the results are unpredictable" which sucks from the programmer point of view because it's completely out of your control. Or fragment shaders would have to lock the pixels they are updating, which would make GPUs far more complicated and expensive, and the performance would suck. Or fragment shaders would execute in some defined order (eg top left to bottom right) instead of in parallel, which wouldn't need locks but the performance would suck even more.